# Voltage regulation at full load

Tags: transmission-line, linear-regulator, input-impedance, transmission, load-regulation

> [image]

The voltage regulation is I(Rcosa -Xsina)/Vr

For leading pf

Here %of regulation=(VRcosa-Vxsina)/Vr ×100 %=((4×0.8)-(6×0.6))/100 ×100% =-0.4

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I tried my best to try to structure your question so that it makes sense, but I still don't understand it.

Comment: Its a power system transmission line problem... thanks for trying it for me